# Binding energy in lorentz boost

Tags: special-relativity, string-theory, mass-energy

In the first lecture here- [M theory and string theory lecture 1, Leonard Susskind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25haxRuZQUk&list=PLA2FDCCBC7956448F&index=1&pp=iAQB&ab_channel=Stanford)

The lecturer gives a heuristic as to why a string of length $L$ has mass $L$.
Set all $h=c=1$.

His explanation is that relativistically the internal energy of mass $m$ is $m$.

On the other hand he uses the light cone trick in order to use nonrelativistic arguments to analyze the string:

If you lorentz boost in the $z$ direction a lot, the energy becomes up to a const $p_{x,y}^2/p_z + m^2/p_z$. Thus intuitively the mass here $p_z$ (Because of $p_{x,y}^2/p_z$; changing the momentum is hit by a factor of $p_z$), and the binding energy is $m^2/p_z$ since it doesn't depend on the momentum.

Also a string of length $L$ easily is calculated to have energy $L^2$ as a nonrelativistic spring.

Overall, we conclude that in this boost $L^2 = m^2$ (he ignores the $p_z$, I guess we fix it large and just claim they're proportional).

Thus we deduce $L = m$ as desired.

My question is how do we make the heuristic more precise, i.e how do we deduce $L^2 ~ m^2$ in the boost? In which sense is $m^2/p_z$ in the boost really the binding energy, and what does that really mean?